# how to use svg.xml in other drawable.xml with tint color

Tags: android, xml, svg

ic_add_inner.xml

```
<vector android:height="19dp" android:viewportHeight="54" android:viewportWidth="54" android:width="19dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="@color/white" android:fillType="evenOdd" android:pathData="M29,25V17H25L25,25L17,25V29L25,29L25,37H29V29L37,29V25L29,25Z"/></vector>
```

svg use android:fillColor="@color/white" to set color white

ic_add_inner.xml use in ImageView

```
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     app:roundPercent="100"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_add_inner"
     app:tint="@color/black"/>
```

ImageView can use app:tint to change svg color from white to black

ic_add.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue_1"/>
        <corners android:radius="999dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add_inner" android:height="@dimen/dp_23" android:width="@dimen/dp_23" android:gravity="center" /></layer-list>
```

ic_add.xml contains a shape blue rectangle and white svg ic_add_inner.xml,
how can i change ic_add_inner.xml color to grey or black in ic_add.xml

Comment: I didn't really get you question.. Are you saying you to remove the blue like background and turn it gray or. Please make your question clear, i want to help. And share the code were you set android:tint

Comment: Please update your question with your actual code, not screenshots of it

Comment: i has update my question , my english is poor . sorry

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i has put code , if you understand again , i will update my question.